# URL rewrite with .htaccess make duplicate mysql entries

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If rewrite url with .htaccess, all INSERT query with php is performed twice (unwanted duplication)

My **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And **index.php**:

```
<?php define('DB_LOGIN', 'mylogin');
define('DB_PASS', 'mypass');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

$mysql = MySQL_Connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASS);
$mysql_db = MySQL_Select_DB(DB_NAME);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`) VALUES ('TEST', 'test')"); ?>
```

After one load of index.php, I have two same entries in mysql.
All is OK when I remove .htaccess, so, problem must be there. The rewrite definition in .htaccess is taken from Wordpress - i like it.

I try Medoo framework, but entries is still duplicate.

So, any suggestion? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers automatically request the favicon.ico file by default. 

But you don't have any favicon.ico file so it is rewritten (rule in your htaccess).

This is why you have a duplicate execute.

Solutions:

1. Add a favicon.ico file
2. Don't INSERT (in index.php) if url requested is favicon
3. Disallow it in your htaccess with a rule

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried your solution, but still have 2 entries in DB. In sql query I tried put `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so in DB I see both requests. If execute (for example) mysite.com/dashboard, to the DB is saved from request_uri: `/dashboard` and `/favicon.ico`. 

So I tried put `favicon.ico` to my server and everything is OK, even without your solution (recognization of rewriten url). Is this OK, or would it be better to fix the missing favicon in .htaccess?

Comment: Nice reaction to debug :) i edited my answer to explain the issue with favicon

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can set a primary or unique key in your SQL table (for example, 'title'). That alone would prevent any duplicate entries.