# PDO Inserting Twice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple `index.php` for testing purposes, with **nothing else**.

### index.php

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->exec('set names utf8');

$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO events(name, description) VALUES (?, ?)');
$query->execute(array('test', 'test2'));
exit;
```

My table is clean before executing the code above, and for every refresh, I get two extra rows.

I've used PDO in the past and it never happened to me previously. I have no idea why it's inserting twice.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Open access.log and check requests. The most obvious reason is that you have apache which tries to load `favicon` and refers to index.php

Comment: @u_mulder That makes sense. I restarted apache and it's not inserting twice anymore! Not sure how restarting apache fixed it tho.

Comment: I've seen this type of problem many a time and have yet to see an answer on Stack about what @u_mulder said (least, I never saw one). I think the question deserves an/his answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not sure if I should answer because I don't have a solution) Just to check apache)

Comment: @u_mulder If it's about risking to be downvoted (which won't be me, *au contraire*), then you could post a community wiki; it's your call. I'd simply put exactly what you wrote in the comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, not downvoting, but answer like `Check your webserver, it makes 2 requests instead of 1` is not a good answer)

Comment: @u_mulder I understand. Well, I think I found a possible dupe; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055885/php-run-once-and-insert-twice-in-mysql-database what do you think? This after a quick Google search for "inserts twice in database apache mysql php favicon" and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182407/url-rewrite-with-htaccess-make-duplicate-mysql-entries

Comment: @u_mulder Your comment disappeared because I duped it with the one you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182407/url-rewrite-with-htaccess-make-duplicate-mysql-entries - *Cheers*